# Mongo Search for Month and Day Only

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to be able to do a Mongo search for all records matching the day and month, but not the year. For instance, given a record set like the following:

```
{
    "lastName" : "a",
    "date" : ISODate("1983-05-29T09:32:11.888Z"),
}, {
    "lastName" : "b",
    "date" : ISODate("1959-05-29T09:32:11.888Z"),
}, {
    "lastName" : "c",
    "date" : ISODate("1983-06-29T09:32:11.888Z"),
}
```

I would like a and b to be returned when passing in some form of `05/29`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the $where condition

```
 db.collection.find({$where : function() { return this.date.getMonth() == month && this.date.getDate() == day} })
```

You should replace the variables 'month' and 'day' with the actual values you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below aggregation query. Please look at [$dayOfMonth](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) and [$month](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) for more details.

```
db.test.aggregate(
 { "$project": {    
      "lastName": 1,      
      "month":{"$month":"$date"},      
      "day": { "$dayOfMonth":"$date" }  
 },
 { "$match":{           
      "month": 5,       
      "day": 29 
   }
 })
```